# Cherrytree note taker in kubuntu 2020

Tags: kubuntu

Let me preface this by saying, I'm just a NOOB user trying to get some work done.

I use an app called Cherrytree (note taker). It is now a snapd. I can no longer access notes that are very important to me.

I've tried recopying from backups. I've tried rebooting.

Please Help

Comment: Problem is solved. Please remove problem. I found a way to access the file. Sorry. Not much of a troubleshooter

Comment: You can always post your own answer here. Others with the same or similar question may benefit.

Comment: I had the same problem after having upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. I found the explanation [here](https://github.com/giuspen/cherrytree/issues/663) and the solution [here](https://snapcraft.io/cherrytree). And then CherryTree worked within minutes. BTW, the problem was that the tree structure was not be traversable. And I had the problem on 2 different computers with Ubuntu 20.04 GNOME.